# Swift: Accessing C Struct Members That Are Objects

Tags: c, swift, pointers, struct, foundation

## What I Have Right Now:

In my app, I have a global C struct that holds colors:

```
//Colors.h

extern struct MYColors *appColors;

struct MYColors
{
    CGColorRef appBackgroundColor;
    // ...Lots more colors follow
};
```

And the matching implementation file:

```
//Colors.m

struct MYColors *appColors = calloc(1, sizeof(struct MYColors));
appColors->appBackgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(23.0f/255.0f, 24.0f/255.0f, 26.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);
```

This allows me to centralize all my app's colors. In various custom views, I write code like this in Objective-C:

```
- (void) updateLayer {
    someCGLayer.backgroundColor = appColors->appBackgroundColor;
}
```

---

## What I Need:

I'm starting to migrate this app to Swift and I have not been able to figure out how I can access the imported version of this C Struct. I've seen lots of posts for simple structs that contain `int`, `float`, etc.

If I have a global instance (basically a singleton) of this struct, `appColors`, how do I access the members of that struct from Swift?

---

## What I Thought Would Work:

This does not work. Swift claims that `MYColors` has no `appBackgroundColor`:

```
let color: CGColor = UnsafePointer<MYColors>(appColors).appBackgroundColor
```

I also thought maybe I just needed to access the singleton like this:

```
let color: CGColor = UnsafePointer<MYColors>(MyModuleName.appColors!).appBackgroundColor
```

But that does not work either.

Comment: For context: The reason I create a singleton that holds all my CGColors is two-fold: (1) it lets me allocate each color once instead of thousands of times across hundreds of views—accessing the color instance from a struct is much faster than constantly creating a new instance of it in every drawing method. (2) I support Dark Mode on macOS 10.11+ and when my users change the mode, I simply recreate all the colors in this struct and tell my app to redraw—it lets me quickly change the whole theme of the app and my views don't need to worry whether they're in dark or light mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C declaration

```
extern struct MYColors * appColors;
```

is imported to Swift as

```
public var appColors: UnsafeMutablePointer<MYColors>!
```

Dereferencing a pointer is done in Swift via the `pointee` property, so the Swift equivalent of the (Objective-)C code

```
appColors->appBackgroundColor
```

is

```
appColors.pointee.appBackgroundColor
```

The type of that value is `Unmanaged<CGColor>!` because the Swift compiler does not know how the memory of the object should be managed. In your case the caller is not responsible for releasing the object, so the final code is:

```
let bgColor = appColors.pointee.appBackgroundColor.takeUnretainedValue()
```

For more information about unmanaged references, see [`Unmanaged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged).

*Remark:* If `appColors` and all struct members are guaranteed to be non-NULL when accessed then you can annotate them with `_Nonnull` in the interface:

```
struct MYColors {
    CGColorRef _Nonnull appBackgroundColor;
    // ...
};

extern struct MYColors * _Nonnull appColors;
```

The Swift compiler then imports the variables as non-optionals instead of (implicitly unwrapped) optionals.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR! "Pointee" is exactly what I needed.